# About unlicensed files

Tags: gpl, lgpl

I was trying to release a library with LGPL license. However I had discovered that many time ago I copied and pasted in the library a header file defining some constants. This file was found on the internet, no license on top of it, I don't know how released it. As such, the unknown author holds the full copyright (berne convention).

What should I do? Can't I release the library under LGPL license?

The constants represent the mapping of audio notes and their frequency, nothing "secret" or "hidden", so if needed, I may change the name of the constants (I know, it's embarrassing).

Comment: How litigious is the author? This sounds like it could be analogous to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_LLC_v._Oracle_America,_Inc, which is still ongoing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, the default license is “all rights reserved”. On the other hand, facts are not copyrightable.

If any reasonable representation of these facts would result in the essentially same header file, there is an argument that there is nothing copyrightable in the header file (compare the US [merger doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idea%E2%80%93expression_distinction) concept, though there's similar case law in the EU). Copyrightable aspects might also involve the structure and organization of the file. In particular, if you're in a jurisdiction that recognizes database rights (such as the EU), a collection of facts can be copyrightable as well.

Personally, if this was as fairly small snippet (e.g. < 10 lines) I'd probably feel sufficiently comfortable using it without any license. For example, I've often copied code snippets that have no reasonable other representation like “array with the first 100 primes” or “declaration for a PI constant”. Just yesterday, I “plagiarized” the structure of a C assert() macro from the GNU libc.

In your particular example, you could likely take the frequencies from publicly available sources such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies) and write your own header file, avoiding all of these concerns. Yes, Wikipedia is also copyrighted, but you would merely use it as a source of facts.

Comment: So are you suggesting to rewrite the header and change the name of the variables? Actually these constants are, for example: `#define NOTE_F1  44`. There is not much space to meaningful rewriting unless awkward nomenclature.

Comment: and the constants in this header are 90

Comment: @fabiuz7 That looks like pure data that could be reasonable to copy without a license. But depending on your use case it could make sense to only use the defines you need, or to organize the defines differently than with defines, e.g. as a struct or array. And to be super anal, the rounding of the frequencies to integers might be a creative expression.

Comment: One worthwhile change you could make might be to include the unit, e.g. `NOTE_F1_HZ` if the value is a frequency in Hertz.  (I'm not saying that would be enough to prevent it qualifying as a derived work, but it would be helpful to anyone reading code using it!)